# How can I create custom catalog prices

Tags: catalog-price-rules

Hi is it possible to create custom catalog prices for example by the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do yes, its a two part process. If you are looking to have it done by manufacturer, then you will likely already have part of it setup.

**Attribute Setup**

If you review the Attributes from Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes and look for manufacturer (it should already exist, but if not you'll need to create it, or any other attributes you might want to use for discounts).

Set the option of: **Use for Promo Rule Conditions** To Yes,

Ensure that the attribute in question exists in the attribute set that you wish to use for your product(s).

Update the product to ensure that the manufacturer is set.

**Catalog Price Rule**

Now if you goto Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules and select Add New.

You'll need to configure a number of components here but of particular interest is the Conditions Tab, if you click on the green Plus symbol, you should have listed Manufacturer under product attributes. Set this to the manufacturer you wish a discount to apply to.

Actions are used to define what kind of discount that will be applied to the product.

When you save this rule you will need to apply the price rules, but when you look at the product you should see a discount exists. Alternatively, instead of catalog price rules, you might wish to apply this as a Shopping Cart Price Rule, the configuration is slightly different but would apply the discount in the checkout rather than globally on the website.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you very much. We rather use the catalog price while our B2B customer need to know their buying price. Kind regards. Christian